# New to CLI. How do I create a shortcut to directories?

Tags: linux, command-line

Installed **Apache** and the default working directory is `/var/www`, when I'm in `/root` I don't want to navigate to `/var/www` every time I want to get some work done.

Can I create a link in `/root` called `web` or something?

I just bought a VPS from Linode, installed Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and learning how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A different solution is to create an alias in your shell.

If you are using bash, put the following in /root/.bashrc:

```
alias cdw="cd /var/www"
```

Next time you login you can type "cdw" and go to that directory.  You can type this from anywhere and be brought to the /var/www directory.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `/root`

```
cd /root
```

and type this:

```
ln -s /var/www web
```

Then you'll have a folder `web` in `/root` that points to `/var/www`

Answer (score 1):

```
ln -s /var/www .
```

will give you a link called `www` to `/var/www` in the current directory.

Comment: I just did `cd www` and it didn't point me to /var/www. Any way to do this?

Comment: @eveo: It did. Try `readlink -f .`.